# How to display List<Object> values in a Label

Tags: c#

I'm trying to display a value of a `List<object>` in a label text. I have created a List Box, where I have loaded the values of the `List<Object>`. Now I want the label to display the selected value of the `List<object>` when it's clicked in the List Box.

I have tried using `label1.Text = frm.CityName.ToString();`
but it returns an error

```
public  void WeatherReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ForecastForm frm = new ForecastForm();
    List<ForecastForm> fWeather = new List<ForecastForm>();
    fWeather.Add(new ForecastForm
    {
        CityName = "Cape Town",
        dateTime = new DateTime(2019, 01, 01),
        MinTemp = 15,
        MaxTemp = 25,
        cPrep = 80,
        cHumid = 60,
        WindSpeed = 154
    });

    foreach (ForecastForm details in fWeather)
    {
        lstCityNames.Items.Add(String.Format(details.CityName));
    }
}

private void lstCityNames_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wReport.Text = string.Join(",", x.CityName.Select(x => x.CityName).ToList());
}
```

Comment: `but it returns an error` ? which error?

Comment: Do you want to see all elements in label or the clicked one?

Comment: `when its clicked in the List Box` So where is your Event Handler for click event of ListBox?

Comment: I want to see all the elements in label

Answer (score 1):

If your `CityName` is a `List<string>` then you can perform `string.Join()` like

```
label1.Text = string.Join(",", frm.CityName);
```

(OR) are you trying to get it from `List<ForecastForm>()`? In such case as well use the same `string.Join()` like below. Import `using System.Linq`

```
label1.Text = string.Join(",", frm.CityName.Select(x => x.CityName).ToList());
```

Comment: i have tried using that one , it still gives an Error the Idea of the application is When i click an element in the List box it should show all the elements of the List<object> in a label

Answer (score 1):

> When i click an element in the List box it should show all the elements of the List in a label

Your actual data is in listbox `lstCityNames` so cast items in this listbox to string and with `string.Join` you can display all `Items`s with comma (`,`) separated string in your Label control.

So try below,

```
private void lstCityNames_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wReport.Text = string.Join(",", lstCityNames.Items.Cast<String>().ToList());
}
```

Comment: fWeather does not exit in the Current context been getting the same error since yesterday @er-sho

Comment: Try this => `wReport.Text = string.Join(",", lstCityNames.Items.Cast<String>().ToList());`

Comment: @CalculusStudent, What happen? Does above code in comment works?

Comment: @CalculusStudent,  Which problem did you face now?

Answer (score 0):

Hie  @Calculus Student welcome to stackoverflow

Try this
Make sure to add your code in the selectedIndexChanged event or a button Click event

```
PutYouLabelNameHere.Text = lstCityNames.SelectedItem.ToString
```